# How to limit calls for a function, but to surely process it afterwards

Tags: python, limit

I have the following code in a class:

```
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    self.__dict__['d'][key] = value
    ...
    self.saveToIni()
```

The `saveToIni` function saves all the dict's items to an ini file at every object's `setattr` call. If 80 `setattr` calls are made in the last 120ms, then the file will be written from scratch every time. The function also orders and sometimes deletes data from the dictonary, so I don't want to change it.

I want to limit the calls to once in, let's say, 5 seconds:

1. When the first `setattr` is triggered, a timer starts asynchronicly, still not running `saveToIni`.
2. If any calls are made to `setattr` and the timer is still counting, it will nor fire a timer nor run `saveToIni`.
3. When the timer times out, the `saveToIni` should launch.

Now, I'm not sure how to achieve this behavoir. I've thought about messing with threads, but still didn't found the idea about how to do it.

Comment: Use a Queue, like [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) for example.

Comment: I second the suggestion to use a Queue for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would go, is to create a Timer Thread which runs a **timedSaveToIni** function once every 5 sec. 
I would also have a tag **isSaveRequested** telling this function if it should actually write data to the disk or not.

The **_*setattr*_** function would simply set this tag to true.

Your code would look like this:

```
class Dict:

  def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.isSaveRequested = False
    self.timedSaveToIni()

  def timedSaveToIni(self):
    threading.Timer(5.0, self.timedSaveToIni).start()
    if self.isSaveRequested:
      self.saveToIni()
      self.isSaveRequested = False


  def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    self.__dict__['d'][key] = value
    ...
    self.isSaveRequested = True

  def saveToInit()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd just have the function remember when it was last called and until 5 seconds have passed since the last call just have it block (sleep). That won't really require any sort of threading. Here's an example - just an idea, not specific to your use case.

```
import time

def timed_func():
  while (timed_func.last_use + 5) > time.time():
    time.sleep(1)
  print "I am working..." # Do the job
  timed_func.last_use = time.time()

def main():
  timed_func.last_use = time.time() - 5
  while True:
    timed_func()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```